# On filter not getting the data using filter function using javasctipt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of  object which looks like

```
const data = [{excluded: [{id: "100"}, {id: "200"}], id: "1"}, {excluded: [{id: "300"}, {id: "400"}], id: "2"}, {excluded: [{id: "300"}, {id: "200"}], id: "400"}]
```

Now, Here I am trying to get those values which does not have the given excluded with the following logic.

```
const getvalues = (
  (data, inputId) => {
    return data.filter(bsg => {
      let excludedvalues = (bsg?.excluded || []).map(
        value => value.id
      )
      return !_.includes(excludedvalues, inputId)
    })
  }
)
```

I was expecting , if the given inputId is present in the excluded object then that object should get filterd.

here _ is a `lodsh`

So, is there any thing which i am doing wrong ?

thanks.

Comment: so did any of our answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understood your question, but do you need this?

```
const data = [{excluded: [{id: "100"}, {id: "200"}], id: "1"}, {excluded: [{id: "300"}, {id: "400"}], id: "2"}, {excluded: [{id: "300"}, {id: "200"}], id: "400"}]

const getValues = (data, inputId) => data.filter(dt => dt.excluded.every(obj => obj.id !== inputId));
getValues(data, "300");
```

filter all the data and find only the ones that don't include this value in the excluded array?

The previous code snippet will result in the first element only.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{excluded: [{id: "100"}, {id: "200"}], id: "1"}, 
              {excluded: [{id: "300"}, {id: "400"}], id: "2"}, 
              {excluded: [{id: "300"}, {id: "200"}], id: "400"}
             ]


const getvalues = (
  (data, inputId) => {
    return data.filter(bsg => {
      let excludedvalues = (bsg?.excluded || []).map(
        value => value.id
      )
      return !excludedvalues.includes(inputId.toString())
    })
  }
)
                            
console.log(getvalues(data, 400));
```

Not sure i totally undertsood.

Here with 400 at second argument we filter every array element that has a 400 as and id in an object in the excluded array.